# regex with multiple possible options

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to accomplish this:

This script should read the current directory and print the contents of any file that starts with messages and is possibly followed by a period and a digit.

```
opendir(CURRENT, ".");
@message_file = grep(/message(\.\d+)?/, readdir (CURRENT));
closedir(CURRENT);

foreach $message_file (@message_file) {
        open (FILE, $message_file);
        while(<FILE>){
             print;
}
close(FILE);
}
```

My code still prints out files like `message.txt`.  I am trying to figure out the proper syntax to not include files such as that and only ones with a period and a digit after.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `message.txt` matches the regexp since it begins with `message`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to figure out the proper syntax to not include files such as that and only ones with a period and a digit after.

You can use this **negative lookahead** based regex for that:

```
/^message(?!\.\D)/
```

- `(?!\.\D)` means fail the match if `messages` is followed by a dot and non digit.
- Also better to use anchor `^` for start